# Facebook Open Graph API - action-type & object-type of another application (foursquare)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, action, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps

I am trying to retrieve a user's foursquare checkin data that is published using the open graph to Facebook. I am generally having trouble finding information (namespace, action-types and object-types) about an application that I do not own.

So far my application has successfully asked the user for (what I believe are) the appropriate permissions to access data that they have submitted to the foursquare FB application:

```
user_actions:playfoursquare
```

I found 'playfoursquare' from the url when I visit a foursquare application page in the new timeline:

```
http://www.facebook.com/[my_username]/app_playfoursquare
```

Now I am trying to query the Graph Api using a url with the following structure: (ref: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/#retrieve)

```
GET /me/{namespace}:{action-type}/{object-type}
```

Now, in the meta data of a [foursquare venue page](https://foursquare.com/v/the-southampton-arms/4b2e6888f964a520a3df24e3) I found a og:type of 'playfoursquare:venue'.

So far I have what I suspect are the *namespace* and *object-type*. I'm just short and *action-type*.

From a user's foursquare application page on Facebook (http://www.facebook.com/[my_username]/app_playfoursquare) there is a lot of references to 'check-ins' so I have made an assumption about the action-type and concluded that the graph api request should be:

```
me/playfoursquare:{checkins,check-ins,check_ins}/venue
```

I tried all above variations of 'check in' and they all return:

> OAuthException - Unknown path component - 2500

I can't believe that this detective work is the best way to determine the properties of another application on the Open Graph. I guess I am missing something obvious.

Either way I would appreciate any help anyone can offer here. I'm at a bit of a loss.

Thanks,
Gfte

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, currently, while its easy to find the namespace of another application (inspect some html, look at URLs) - its not possible to find the action names used by another app - you have to guess.

But for Foursquare, after doing some trial and error myself, I've been able to determine that their current actions are GET-able at the following URLs:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/playfoursquare:checkin_to?access_token=TOKEN
https://graph.facebook.com/me/playfoursquare:became_the_mayor_of?access_token=TOKEN
https://graph.facebook.com/me/playfoursquare:unlock?access_token=TOKEN
```

once you have the `user_actions:playfoursquare` and/or `friends_actions:playfoursquare` permissions.

Comment: This is absolutely spot on. Thanks very much. So you just used trial and error to determine those? That was some good guesswork.