# Find locations of checkins from foursquare friends using v2 API?

Tags: facebook, api, foursquare

How is it possible to get the locations of a user's friends nearby(within X km) with v2 or real-time user push of FourSquare API please?

And can those friends be the same friends as the ones from facebook account automatically added (for those fb friends of the user that also login with their fb account to 4sqr too), or, when a user joins 4sqr via fb can they register to an app using 4sqr API and then have that app specify somehow what his friends could be and make them all part of the same group whose last checkins could be searched?

In other words, I would like to list all nearby 4sqr friends that are in the same group (list?) along with a last time stamp of their checkins. Can this be done and how please? Which APIs should I use along with OAuth or something?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the API docs (https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/), it doesn't seem that you'll be able to get the information you are looking for.

It looks like you'll be able to get real time pings when a user that is using your app checks in somewhere. But you can't get just any foursquare user's real time checkin events.

Unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is possible, at least until the Graph API v1.0 is still working (until April 30th, 2015), because then all the friends_* permissions will be removed. Have a look at the answer at

[Facebook Open Graph API - action-type & object-type of another application (foursquare)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821375/facebook-open-graph-api-action-type-object-type-of-another-application-four)

You need to request the `user_actions:playfoursquare` and `friends_actions:playfoursquare` permissions first ([Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#reference-opengraph)).

Then, you should be able to request the checkins via

```
/me/playfoursquare:checkin_to
```

or

```
/me/friends/playfoursquare:checkin_to
```